# Connecting to shopify and returning products

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, shopify

I'm tring to return products from my shopify store and dump the expected returned json on to the page.  No products return via the code but if I go directly to the url in the form below I get the expected json displayed on the page:

```
https://API_KEY:PASSWORD@your-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

Can anyone help me return the json using [this package](https://github.com/joshrps/laravel-shopify-API-wrapper) which I'm using to connect to shopify?  I'm also using Laravel 5.

I've noticed that the Input calls return nothing:

```
Input::get('code');
Input::all();
```

I added this to app.php:

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR #22: The requested URL returned error: 401
in api.php line 309 at API->call(array('METHOD' => 'GET', 'URL' => '/admin/products.json?page=1')) in routes.php line 87
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/show_products', function() {

$shopify = App::make('ShopifyAPI');

// This creates an instance of the Shopify API wrapper and
// authenticates our app.
$shopify = App::make('ShopifyAPI', [
  'API_KEY' => 'api_key',
  'API_SECRET' => 'api_secret',
  'SHOP_DOMAIN' => 'shop_domain.myshopify.com',
  'ACCESS_TOKEN' => 'access_token'
]);

$shopify->installURL(['permissions' => array('read_products', 'write_products'), 'redirect' => 'https://dev.shopify.com/public/']);

try {
      $verify = $shopify->verifyRequest(Input::all(), true);
      if ($verify)
      {
        $code = Input::get('code');
        echo "code: ".$code; // no code returned
        $accessToken = $shopify->getAccessToken($code);
        echo "accessToken: ".$accessToken; // no access token
      }
      else
      {
        echo "issue with data";
        // Issue with data
      }

} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo '<pre> Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</pre>';
}

// Gets a list of products

  $result = $shopify->call([
    'METHOD'     => 'GET',
    'URL'         => '/admin/products.json?page=1'
  ]);

$products = $result->products;
print_r($products);
exit;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on Android. The accessing the products by the url with key/secret worked fine if I was in a browser, but failed trying to do a basic GET against that URL from the device.
I couldn't figure out why, but I ended up setting the header on the request, and that worked well.

Where you had

```
https://API_KEY:PASSWORD@your-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

Instead, request

```
https://your-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

but set the header `x-shopify-access-token` to `PASSWORD`